# How to migrate OctoPi to new camera stack without reinstall?

Tags: octopi

The new OctoPi camera stack is reported to be lighter, more efficient, and overall better. Old camera stack sometimes loses access to my camera during print, and only regains it after restart. Thus, obviously, I want to try the new one. Maybe it'll help with my specific problem, maybe it won't, but it has to be at least slightly better. I do not want to lose my uploaded files, Octolapse lapses, plugin config etc.

So, is there a way to upgrade to the new camera stack without reinstall? Or to save plugins, configs and files to restore them after reinstall?

Comment: Great question. I would love to do exactly the same thing. If I get to it and figure it out, I'll let you know. If you do earlier, please share. I'm currently in two long prints, I think you can use the built-in Backup and Restore. If you have two SD cards, I guess make a backup, write new stack to another SD, restore backup, test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think many problems could arise from doing this manually such as missing or incompatible dependencies. As I had to do the same I just tested the following successfully:

### Making a backup of the OctoPi configuration (required)

- Login on the OctoPi web ui
- Click settings
- Under OctoPrint (left menu) click on 'Backup & Restore'
- Click 'Create backup now' and when finished download the backup

### Make a backup of the entire SD card (optional)

You can make a full bit-to-bit copy (image) of the SD card as a backup **or use another SD card for testing it first.** On Windows you can for example download [Win32DiskImager](https://win32diskimager.org/) and make a full image/backup of the SD card.

### Flashing OctoPi with the new camera stack

- Download and open [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)
- Choose 'Other specific-purpose OS' followed by '3D printing' and 'OctoPi'
- Choose the 'OctoPi (new camera stack)' as shown below
- Insert another SD card for testing or override your current SD card after you've made the backups as described above
- Choose other specific settings if desired such as WiFi et cetera
- Flash to SD card

[image: Raspberry Pi Imager]

### Restoring the OctoPi configuration

- When finished, place the SD card in the Pi and start it up
- When the Pi started open the Web UI again on the Welcome Wizard click Next
- On the 'Restore Backup' screen select the backup you've made on the first step and wait for all plugins to install, config to be restored and Pi to restart